# How to change headline of table of contents in R Markdown Powerpoint presentation?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to change the text "Table of Contents" to "Inhalt" in the pptx presentation. How could I do this? This is what I tried:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "STAT-UP"
date: "28/09/2020"
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    toc: true
lang: de-DE
header-includes:
  - \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
  - \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
---

## R Markdown

## Slide with Bullets
```

Comment: The specification you set in `header-includes` only works with latex (PDF generation with beamer), and has nothing to do with pptx generation.

Comment: Why don't you use [`officedown`](https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown) package? It may provide more flexible solution.

Comment: Thanks I will look into `officedown`. I hoped, it would be possible to change this in standard powerpoint output, e.g. using the language option

Answer (score 0):

`toc-title: "Inhalt"` on the YAML section changes the title of TOC. So, the following example can produce a pptx file with *Inhalt* rather than *Table of contents*.

```yaml
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Your Name"
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    toc: true
  officedown::rpptx_document:
    toc: true
    base_format: "bookdown::powerpoint_presentation2" # For cross-reference of Figs/Tabs
    keep_md: TRUE
toc-title: "Inhalt"
---

## Slide 1

This is a slide.

## Slide 2

This is a slide, too.
```

By the code above, you will get a pptx file as follows:

[image]

By the way, **I don't think `lang` key supports pptx outputs**. Since Pandoc official manual mentions [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#language-variables) that `lang` key "affects most formats, and controls hyphenation in PDF output when using LaTeX (through babel and polyglossia) or ConTeXt," the key seems to only support PDF and HTML generation and the key has nothing to do with the translation of any header (e.g. "Table of contents" to German "Inhalt", "Table 1" to Spanish "Tabla 1").